# c++ map with custom key is size 3 but only iterates 2 elements?

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading, ordereddictionary, c++-faq

I am trying to create an ordered map with my struct `Tenor` as key. Ordered map requires `operator<` , so I define it for my struct (currently just a *placeholder*, always returns `true` - this seems to cause problem Q1). In this example I insert 3 elements. But, as per below example, as I iterate through my map, it only iterates through 2 elements, not 3.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct Tenor {
    public:
        string _label;

        Tenor(string label = "3M")
        {
            _label = label;
        }

        // Placeholder for now
        bool operator<(Tenor const& obj) const
        {
            return true;
        }
};

void tenor_operator_ordered() {
    auto t1 = Tenor {"1M"};
    auto t2 = Tenor {"2M"};
    auto t3 = Tenor {"3M"};
    map<Tenor, int> mp;
    mp[t1] = 1; //insert
    mp[t3] = 3; 
    mp[t2] = 2;

    // Check if items are available?
    int item;
    item = mp.find(t1)->second;
    std::cout << item << '\n';
    item = mp.find(t2)->second;
    std::cout << item << '\n';
    item = mp.find(t3)->second;
    std::cout << item << '\n';

    cout << "Size: " << mp.size() << endl;
  
    // Printing Test objects in sorted order 
    for (auto x : mp) 
        cout << x.first._label << " " << x.second << endl;

}
```

My output:

```bash
469761104
469761104
469761104
Size: 3
3M 3
1M 1
```

**Question 1: why for loop iterates through 2 elements only?**

**Question 2: why `item` is not the map's Value (for each given Key)?**
Update 1: thanks to the comments, it seems like my *placeholder* is not appropriate, and breaks the map algorithm.

Comment: If a map was able to function with a placeholder `<`, it wouldn't require one in the first place. The program has UB because the `<` doesn't create a strict weak order (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare).

Comment: `// Placeholder for now` A placeholder that doesn't follow strict weak ordering won't work once you actually try to use it with something like a map that has that requirement in order to function properly.

Comment: Works fine once `operator<` is fixed. https://godbolt.org/z/fY6v9jGvj

Comment: @RetiredNinja thank you so much, could you elaborate on why strict weak ordering in required in  map algorithm? As I am going to need to write my own **proper** `operand<` for production version of this example.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LessThanComparable are worth a read.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, thank you very much. If you post these as answer I am happy to accept.

Comment: The reason the standard often requires comparators that define a strict weak ordering is that known algorithms assume it.   When/if researchers develop an algorithm without such a requirement, the standard will presumably be updated to relax such requirements (may take a while, don't hold your breath).  In the meantime, you need to eliminate the undefined behaviour from your "placeholder" (e.g. write the `operator<()` to `return _label < obj.label_`, and use fact that comparing `std::string`s does a lexicographical comparison, which does imply [at least] a strict weak ordering).

Comment: strict weak ordering is the minimum you need as relation between the elements to sort them, because if `a < b` and `b < a` at the same time, then there is no way to order `a` and `b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by the comments, using an arbitrary `operator<` which *doesn't follow strict weak order* is **wrong**. The operator overload must ensure that if a<b, then b>a. Otherwise it's undefined behaviour.